# How to pass two queries from in to one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want this two methods pass to one view :

```
 public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getProfitSum()
        {
            var profBalance = db.Profits
   .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
   .GroupBy(x => x.IdUser.UserId)
   .Select(x => new ProfitAndCostViewModel { ProfitSum = x.Sum(y => y.Value) })
   .ToList();
            return profBalance;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getCostSum()
        {
            var costBalance = db.Costs
   .Where(x => x.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
   .GroupBy(x => x.IdUser.UserId)
   .Select(x => new ProfitAndCostViewModel { CostSum = x.Sum(y => y.Value) })
   .ToList();
            return costBalance;
        }
```

in my ActionResult I Have this:

```
var pcv = new ProfitAndCostViewModel();
            pcv.ProfModel =getProfitSum();
            pcv.CostModel =getCostSum();

             return View(pcv);
```

And in ProfitAndCostViewModel code is this:

```
public double ProfitSum { get; set; }
        public double CostSum { get; set; }
        public double FinalBalance { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> ProfModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> CostModel { get; set; }
```

this is the error: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel]'.`

Comment: Check model you're passing to a view and model in a view, it's different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel>`:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel>
```

but here you are passing a single `ProfitAndCostViewModel` instance to it:

```
var pcv = new ProfitAndCostViewModel();
pcv.ProfModel =getProfitSum();
pcv.CostModel =getCostSum();
return View(pcv);
```

So you should fix the model to which your view is typed:

```
@model ProfitAndCostViewModel
```

Comment: i make this like you said but now error is this : oreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel' because 'WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Then fix your foreach: `@foreach (var item in Model.ProfModel) { ... }` instead of `foreach(var item in Model)`. Same for the `CostModel` property if you are using it in your view. That's basic C#.